# Why can't i pass mode to the discriminator function in tensorflows GANEstimator?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

When using the GANEstimator in the tensorflow library, I can only pass the mode to the generator function but not the discriminator function. This means I can not perform batch normalisation or dropout in the discriminator. Is there a reason why this is not allowed? Will this be changed in the future?

Link to GANEstimator:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/gan/estimator/GANEstimator

Answer (score 0):

This feature has been added already:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/9560054b18ad3fc9faa296d344e062876858817a